# error while connecting input node to AVAudioSinkNode

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

I get an error when connecting nodes

```
let sourceNode = AVAudioSinkNode { (test1, frameCount, audioBufferList) -> OSStatus in
    print("callback", self.testInteger)
    return noErr
}
audioEngine.attach(sourceNode)
audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: sourceNode, format: nil)
```

[aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp: 1086: Initialize: failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf <2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf <2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)

And after that errors when `try audioEngine.start ()`

[avae] AVAEInternal.h: 88 required condition is false: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1415:Initialize: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid (inputHWFormat))]
[avae] AVAudioEngine.mm:160 Engine @ 0x2836a8940: could not initialize, error = -10875
[avae] AVAEInternal.h: 88 required condition is false: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1415:Initialize: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid (inputHWFormat))]

I also tried

```
audioEngine.connect (audioEngine.inputNode, to: sourceNode, format: audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat (forBus: 0))
```

and

```
audioEngine.connect (audioEngine.inputNode, to: sourceNode, format: audioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat (forBus: 0))
```

in these two cases the application crashes with an error
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid (format)"

Comment: The `format: nil` is wrong.

Comment: @matt yes, I realized that this is wrong, but I still do not understand what I should use instead, I tried other formats (I wrote about this in my question) but they also do not work. can you tell me which format should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was necessary to put the category of the audio session playAndRecord

```
try audioSession.setCategory (.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
```

under this condition, this option works

```
audioEngine.connect (audioEngine.inputNode, to: sourceNode, format: audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat (forBus: 0))
```